# Javascript ternary operator result

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I am making small utility to compile javascript block using C#. I am trying to understand ternary operator's execution flow. Now when I am running a javascript using Chrome or Firefox :

```
var k = 27;
var o = 78;
var a = k < 100 ? o+=2 > 11 ? "T" : "F" : o < 100 ? "J" : "P";
alert(a);
```

It should have give me result **"T"** or **"F"** if **"o+=2"** returns false. But instead of those it returns **"78F"**. Can anyone please explain me whats the logic behind it.

Comment: I would recommend NOT nesting ternary operators. While it's always nice to have a one-liner, It's much easier for other developers to understand if you split this into if-else statements. I once had to work on an application with up to 6 nested ternaries in parts. It was a beast to debug.

Comment: please use braces `(` and `)` to differentiate expressions and make it easier for everyone's eyes. It'll most probably give you the desired result as well.

Comment: Nesting ternaries is a terrible idea..

Comment: I am making a javascript compiler. I generally dont write code like this. But compiler should take anything from user if there is no syntax error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the [operator precedence table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence):

> Assignment operators has less priority than a comparison operator.

So your code will be evaluated like below,

1. var a = k < 100 ? o+=2 > 11 ? "T" : "F" : o < 100 ? "J" : "P";
2. var a = `true` ?  o += 2 > 11 ? "T" : "F" : o < 100 ? "J" : "P";
3. var a = `true` ?  o += `false` ? "T" : "F" : o < 100 ? "J" : "P";
4. var a = `true` ?  o += `"F"` : o < 100 ? "J" : "P";
5. var a = `true` ?  `"78F"` : o < 100 ? "J" : "P";
6. var a = `"78F"`

And you can correct the behaviour by grouping the condition using a parenthesis,

```
var a = (k < 100) ? (o+=2) > 11 ? "T" : "F" : (o < 100) ? "J" : "P";
console.log(a); // T
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var k = 27;
var o = 78;
var a = k < 100 ? (o+=2) > 11 ? "T" : "F" : o < 100 ? "J" : "P";
alert(a);
```

Above code works as expected by you.
You probably thought that the `+=` operator would be processed first.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `+=` on `o` instead of just `+`.

```
var a = k < 100 ? o+2 > 11 ? "T" : "F" : o < 100 ? "J" : "P";
```

Also using parentheses will make it more readable:

```
var a = (k < 100 ? (o+2 > 11 ? "T" : "F") : (o < 100 ? "J" : "P"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually working like 
`k < 100 ? o += (2 > 11 ? "T" : "F") : (o < 100 ? "J" : "P");`

because anything on right side of assignment operator `=` is processed first, in Left to Right order, so `2 > 11 ? "T" : "F"` is evaluated first